# How to Convert Int number to Double number?

Tags: javascript, double, int

Using Javascript:

How I can convert one number integer to Double Number Example:

```
100 -> 100.00
```

Answer (score 61):

All numbers in JavaScript *are* doubles: that is, they are stored as 64-bit IEEE-754 doubles.

That is, the goal is not to get a "double": the goal is to get *the string reprsentation of a number formatted as "YYY.XX"*. For that, consider [`Number.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), for instance:

```
(100).toFixed(2)
```

The result is the *string* (not a "double"!) `"100.00"`. The parenthesis are required to avoid a grammar ambiguity in this case (it could also have been written as `100.0.toFixed` or `100..toFixed`), but would not be required if 100 was in a variable.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 14):

JavaScript numbers are already [IEEE 754 floating point numbers](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) ([specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5)). If you want to *format* it (for output), you can use [`toFixed` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 2):

All numbers are stored as doubles in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers are stored as doubles in javascript.
You can use toFixed if you want specific decimal points after the number