# Convert Double to String without precision loss in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert a floating point variable to a string without losing any precision.

I.e. I would like the string to have the same information as my floating point variable contains, since I use the output for further processing (even if it means that the string will be very long and readable).

To put this more clearly, I would like to have functions for cyclic conversion

```
var dA = 323423.23423423e4;
var sA = toString(dA);
var dnA = toDouble(sA);
```

and I would like dnA and dA to be equal

Thanks

PS: Sources on the internet usually talk about how to round strings but I have not found information on exact representation. Also I am not interested in Arbitrary Precision calculations, I just need double precision floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Does the string need to be a base-10 representation of the floating point value?

Comment: @Hogan - ECMA-262 section 4.3.19 specifies that the JavaScript (rather, EcmaScript) internal number representation is a 64-bit IEEE 754 value. Thus, it isn't hardware dependent.

Comment: @TedHopp - Sure but you are only guaranteed 15-17 decimal digits of precision, thus it is easy to construct a string which will be rounded.

Comment: @Hogan - If the round trip was String → Number → String, I'd agree with you. Not every base-10 floating-point string has an exact representation in 64-bit IEEE 754. However, the converse is different: every IEEE 754 floating point number does, in fact, have an _exact_ String representation since it is the sum of a finite set of powers of 2, each of which has a finite representation in base 10. So the round trip Number → String → Number can be done exactly.

Comment: @TedHopp - Yes the question is tricky like that.  Since the OQ is (in fact) string-> number -> string -> number.  eg `var dA = 123456323423.23423423e4; var sA = toString(dA); var dnA = toDouble(sA);` Would have dnA = dA, but not have dA equal the interpreted string "123456323423.23423423e4".  Still, I'm deleting my original comment since you are more correct than I am.

Comment: @TedHopp Base 10 would be nice is not required though.

Comment: so to speak I would like to serialize the double variable and I am just looking for guarantees that the default (rather) implicit conversion like dA + '' is doing this and is not platform/browser specific. I have encountered truncating problems a lot in my scientific career and make it a point to avoid them ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let string arithmetic do the string conversion, and then use `parseFloat` to get it back to a float:

```
var dA = 323423.23423423e4;
var sA = dA + '';
var dnA = parseFloat(sA);
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/fFkVR/) to see it in action.

Note:  [All JavaScript numbers are doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312732/508537), so you don't need to draw a distinction between doubles and floats.  Thus, the only place you'd need to worry about precision loss is in your first line.  For example, if you did `var dA = 987654321.0123456789` for your first line, it would be equivalent to `var dA = 987654321.01234567`, and `dA` would still equal `dnA` in the end.

Comment: this is what I was thinking, however I was worrying whether this rather implicit conversion preserves exactness.

Comment: @holger:  Yes, it will preserve the exactness of the _value_ of `dA`.  However, as mentioned in my note, this value will be less precise than what you declared it to be if your declaration contained too many digits.

Answer (score 2):

Just `dA.toString()` and `parseFloat(sA)` should do it.