# Double.parseDouble is not working on my webpage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add some funds and I want to use Double.parseDouble but, I don't think the page is recognizing double.parseDouble.  I don't get an error but it won't add or pass the values.

Here is my code.

```
function CalculateBudget(){
    var table = document.getElementById('tblBudgetTotals');
    input1600 = 0;
    input1602 = 0;
    input1603 = 0;
    input1608 = 0;
    input1612 = 0;
    funding = 0;
    budgetSum = 0;

          input1600 = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('txt1600').value);
    input1602 = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('txt1602').value);
    input1603 = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('txt1603').value);
    input1608 = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('txt1608').value);
    input1612 = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('txt1612').value);
    funding = Double.parseDouble(document.getElementById('FundingTotals').value);

    budgetSum += Double.parseDouble(input1600) + Double.parseDouble(input1602) + Double.parseDouble(input1603) + Double.parseDouble(input1608) + Double.parseDouble(input1612) + Double.parseDouble(funding);

    document.getElementById('totbud').value = Double.parseDouble(budgetSum);
}
```

Comment: Have you declared a `double` object that contains a `parseDouble` function? If not then I believe you may be looking for `parseFloat` as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: Is there any particular reason this question has a coldfusion tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you should just be using `parseFloat` for this, since according to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312693/how-to-convert-int-number-to-double-number) [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605925/does-javascript-have-double-floating-point-number-precision) all numbers in JavaScript are already "double precision" (64-bit) floats.